# Laravel + ReactJS loose components in blade views. A good practice?

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, laravel-blade

The following is unclear to me. So far, I don't see lose Reactjs components embedded in views, but only in Single Page Applications.

I was wondering if one could use Reactjs in a Laravel application in combination with the blade template engine? I have a Laravel project and I like the way ReactJS binds to the DOM. But I do not need an entire JS SPA.

So is it possible AND a good practice to use different ReactJs components loosely in blade views? For example a React table component and a header message component, that also are able to communicate with each other.

Comment: What's the reason you would like to use React with Laravel?

Comment: Because the views will have certain components, like tables, that will do all kinds of JavaScript/Ajax based actions. I like the DOM binding and structure that React creates. Making components out of it instead of searching the DOM and binding event handlers, as you do with for example jQuery. So I like the idea of JS components on the page. But having a SPA + API feels like overkill.

Comment: Well Personally I never used React in a Laravel project, but I did use Vue actually and I quite like that. Vue is integrated in a fresh project and work right out of the box. Also, Vue offers something called "Inline templates". You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [package](https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel) that does just that.

However I would argue it would be a better practice if you separate the front-end and back-end completely. So you can use Laravel to serve the data using REST API endpoints and then display everything using a React app.

This way they will be loosely coupled and if you ever want to swap out one for the other (e.g. swap out React for Angular) then it would be a lot easier as your api endpoints wouldn't have to change at all.

**EDIT: Some benefits of a headless CMS (taken from [pantheon.io](https://pantheon.io/decoupled-cms)):**

> By shifting responsibility for the user experience completely into the
>   browser, the headless model provides a number of benefits:
>
> - Value: future-proof your website implementation, lets you
>     redesign the site without re-implementing the CMS
> - Sets frontend developers free from
>     the conventions and structures of the backend. Headless development
>     not only eliminates “div-itis”, it gives frontend specialists full
>     control over the user experience using their native tools.
> - Speeds up the site by shifting display logic to the client-side
>     and streamlining the backend. An application focused on delivering
>     content can be much more responsive than one that assembles completely
>     formatted responses based on complex rules.
> - Builds true
>     interactive experiences for users by using your website to power fully
>     functional in-browser applications. The backend becomes the system of
>     record and “state machine”, but back-and-forth interaction happens
>     real-time in the browser.

Lets say you also want to build a mobile app using React Native that would use the same underlying code base as your React web app. If you have a decoupled CMS, so your backend is only serving data then you can make calls to this same backend from both your web app and mobile app without worrying about content types, response formats etc... In-fact, with React Native you can use the same React codebase for the mobile app along with the web app and you would only have to change some views around.

It's a great way to re-use your code with better modularity and seperation of concerns.

Comment: But what is the advantage of having a SPA + API compared to having MVC with loose React components. If I would want to, I could still replace those React components with Angular ones. This way the web application would still be able to function very basically without JavaScript. So it supports the progressive enhancement idea.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show some benefits of a headless CMS.

Comment: @Floris `the web application would still be able to function very basically without JavaScript`, but you want to use React components so you will be using JavaScript either way?

Comment: Yes. I want to use Javascript as an improvement. Not as a requirement. As in progressive enhancement. For example: A table navigation would work with GET requests to view different pages of that table data. But with JS enabled ReactJS will take over and make it a user friendly Ajax based table and show the pages with async calls. So with JS enabled the table will become an actual ReactJS component.